# Autocomplete passed class object

Tags: python, class, parameters, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I have two classes say A and B. B has in its constructor A as a parameter.  Class A has a function foo. Now when I type "a." I want Vs code to autocomplete to show the suggestions "a.foo()". It's not working at the moment. Do I need to type hint or something similar? I've tried to import A but it's not working.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
    def foo(self):
        print("hello")
class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        a. <-- this should show the members of A but does not
```

Running Mac and the Python 2.7 with Microsoft extension.

Comment: can you show an example code

Comment: Fixed it! @Jeril

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python is a dynamically-typed language and your editor can't evaluate the type of parameter `a` passed to constructor of `B` before runtime to show you its attributes.

You can use type hinting to tell you are expecting an `A` object to be passed as parameter `a` to the constructor of `B`:

`def __init__(self, a: A):`

[image]

Without a type hint you can use `ctrl(or command)+space` to see all possible completions.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This was just what I was looking for. I tried this before, however, I'm using Python 2.7 and this is a 3.5 implementation. Any ideas on how to solve it in 2.7?

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#suggested-syntax-for-python-2-7-and-straddling-code It is a suggested syntax and annotation for Python 2 which is not mandatory and some editors may use, and the others may ignore it. As I tested, I think VSCode doesn't support this.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
    def foo(self):
        print("hello")
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
```

now you should be able to:

```py
classexp = B()
classexp.{some A function}
```

Comment: Thank you for the replay. I'm however not trying to inherit class A, I'm just looking to use it class B!